# Possible outcomes of Approximate profile-likelihood estimator (APLE) for spatial autocorrelation

Tags: r, spatial, profile-likelihood

I've been working with spatial autocorrelation for a while and now I'm trying to move from more traditional estimators such as Moran's I or Geary's C to the new APLE estimator. I read Li's papers on APLE and also the reference on R-project. But I am still missing something very basic, as I still didn't understand something: the results of the APLE statistic is said to have a closed form but I didn't figure which one it is.

For instance, while Moran's I can gom from -1 to 1, I couldn't figure which are the possible boundaries of APLE statistics. More interesting, I've been running tests in my older data, using the spdep package in R, and it seems to me that APLE can go up to 2. Any one has any tip on that? Please, any insights here would be very much appreciated.